# Magento 2 UI component- Element argument is not allowed here

Tags: magento2, layout, uicomponent, phpstorm

After upgrade to Magento 2, in IDE PhpStorm, the UI component file show a lot of errors , like `Element argument is not allowed here`, `Element xxx is not allowed here` etc.

But, the UI component file is **working well in system**. And the **official** UI component file **also** has the errors. Like `cms_block_listing.xml`:

[image: Element argument is not allowed here]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to File > Setting > Plugins > search text ('Magento2'); install this plugin after that click **regenerated urn map** and **reindex** in Magento2 Plugin config . Good luck!

Comment: The "Magento2 Plugin" setting is in `File > Settings > Magento2 Plugin`. After click "regenerated urn map" button, we need restart PhpStorm to see effect.

Answer (score 2):

Other than the solution which install `Magento2 Plugin` in PhpStorm, we could also use the **Magento official CLI command**:

```
bin/magento dev:urn-catalog:generate .idea/misc.xml
```

It will generate the **urn map file** which PhpStorm need. **Restart** PhpStorm, then the a lot of errors will disappear.